# Gremlin: otherV() not working inside order().by()

Tags: titan, gremlin, tinkerpop3, gremlin-server

I'm using Tinkerpop 3.0.1 (Titan 1.0.0), and I try to list all edges for a vertex, sorted by degree of the node on the other end of the edge.

I tried:

`g.V(1482896).bothE().order().by(otherV().bothE().count(), decr)`

I get the following error from Titan:

> The path history of the traverser does not contain a previous vertex: [e[1d2m8u-1d70ts-b2t-vs7k][82628848-DIRECTED->1482896]]

The strange thing is, there *is* a previous vertex in the path (namely vertex #1482896. I'm confused on how to solve this one.

Comment: Confusing, indeed. This seems to work for me.

    gremlin> graph = TitanFactory.open('inmemory'); g = graph.traversal()
    ==>graphtraversalsource[standardtitangraph[inmemory:[127.0.0.1]], standard]
    gremlin> v = graph.addVertex('name','jason'); w = graph.addVertex('name','david'); e = v.addEdge('to',w)
    ==>e[17j-3co-1lh-3a0][4344-to->4248]
    gremlin> g.V(v.id()).bothE().order().by(otherV().bothE().count(), decr)
    ==>e[17j-3co-1lh-3a0][4344-to->4248]

Comment: ack, formatting... https://gist.github.com/pluradj/bb2d3a1bea0e1444127a

Comment: @JasonPlurad thanks! I'm using the Berkeley DB storage. This working in memory and failing with Berkeley DB might indicate an actual bug.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Answering my own question, after playing around with this, I found a workaround:

```
g.V(123).bothE().as('edges')
 .otherV().order().by(bothE().count(), decr)
 .select('edges')
```

This will effectively sort edges adjacent to vertex #123 by highest degree of the node on the other end of the edge.